# Why does SauceLabs say my QUnit Test Fails when its clearly passing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, qunit, saucelabs

We are trying to use **SauceLabs** to verify that our browser-based **QUnit** tests are passing in popular device/browser combinations ...

The tests ***PASS*** when we look at them in the browser: https://ordenado.herokuapp.com/

But for some reason SauceLabs is telling us they "failed"...

[image: saucelabs-ordem-test-is-clearly-passing]

See: https://saucelabs.com/tests/5b0f07813a7f4934bb44b07606ea2fd5

### cURL Command Used

For reference, we used the following curl command:

```
curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/ordem/js-tests \
-X POST \
-u ordem:SECRET_KEY \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "platforms": [
      ["Windows 8.1", "internet explorer", "11"],
      ["Windows 8", "internet explorer", "10"],
      ["Windows 8.1", "firefox", "beta"],
      ["Windows 8", "firefox", "37"],
      ["Windows 7", "firefox", "32"],
      ["OS X 10.8", "safari", "6"],
      ["OS X 10.8", "chrome", "37"],
      ["Linux", "chrome", "30"],
      ["Linux", "firefox", "dev"],
      ["OS X 10.10","iphone", "7.0"],
      ["OS X 10.10","iphone", "8.2"],
      ["OS X 10.10","ipad", "7.0"],
      ["OS X 10.10","ipad", "8.2"]
    ],
    "url": "https://qunit.herokuapp.com/test/test.html?coverage=true",
    "framework": "qunit",
    "name":"ordem",
    "public": "public",
    "build": "build-007"
}'
```

Also, does anyone else ever experience the following error:

> "***The Sauce VMs failed to start the browser or device***"

[image: saucelabs-vm-failed]

Visit: https://saucelabs.com/u/ordem for complete list of tests.
click on any of the ones Sauce claims "failed" and watch the video to see the tests passing!!

[image: saucelabs-ordem-test-summary-fails]

Any insight much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add several hooks to report qunit test results from SauceLabs.

There is [an article](https://saucelabs.com/javascript/qunit) how to get started with qunit. There mentioned [repository with example](https://github.com/bernii/yummy-pasta/blob/master/test-qunit/resources/tests.js) where is following code snippet:

```
var log = [];
QUnit.done = function (test_results) {
  var tests = log.map(function(details){
    return {
      name: details.name,
      result: details.result,
      expected: details.expected,
      actual: details.actual,
      source: details.source
    }
  });
  test_results.tests = tests;

  // delaying results a bit cause in real-world
  // scenario you won't get them immediately
  setTimeout(function () { window.global_test_results = test_results; }, 2000);
};
QUnit.testStart(function(testDetails){
  QUnit.log = function(details){
    if (!details.result) {
     details.name = testDetails.name;
     log.push(details);
    }
 }
});
```

Add this code before your tests and results will be reported properly

Comment: thanks for your reply! we had already added that script. see: https://github.com/dwyl/ordem/blob/master/example/index.html#L13 but still get failures in internet explorer on SauceLabs. Also, we are not going *back* to using Grunt... we just want to send a simple/lightweight http (cURL) request to the Sauce API to run our tests.

Comment: What error do you see in report? Is it reproduced permanently?